# Why is the adjustScroll: method being called twice per scroll in NSScrollView?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsscrollview

I have overridden the `adjustScroll:` method within the documentView of my `NSScrollView` in order to investigate how to use it to constrain large scroll movements.

What I am seeing is that for each scroll "event" prior to calling the normal scrolling notifications (which I am listening to elsewhere) it calls the `adjustScroll` method twice(!) and the first time it always seems to call it with a rectangle of size (1,1) - strange?

My method is as follows:

```
override func adjustScroll(newVisible: NSRect) -> NSRect {
    println("Document: adjustScroll: \(newVisible)")
    return super.adjustScroll(newVisible)
}
```

With the results of the `println` being as follows:

> Document: adjustScroll: (1.0, 0.0, **1.0, 1.0**)
>
> Document: adjustScroll: (1.0, 0.0, 1436.0, 855.0)

I only have one "Document" object in my view hierarchy and there is only one scrollView...perplexed.

## EDIT

I have printed out the stack within the `adjustScroll` call. The relevant parts are as follows for each of the two calls:

(1.0,1.0)

> [0   Grid                                0x000000010007d697 _TToFC4Grid8Document12adjustScrollfS0_FVSC6CGRectS1_ + 87,
>
> 1   AppKit                              0x00007fff84368070 -[_NSScrollingConcurrentMainThreadSynchronizer _scrollToCononicalOrigin] + 655,
>
> 2   AppKit                              0x00007fff84367a51 -[_NSScrollingConcurrentMainThreadSynchronizer _synchronize:completionHandler:] + 167,
>
> 3   AppKit                              0x00007fff84367963 __80-[_NSScrollingConcurrentMainThreadSynchronizer initWithSharedData:constantData:]_block_invoke + 144,
>
> 4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010057ed43 _dispatch_client_callout + 8,
>
> ...

(1436.0, 855.0)

> [0   Grid                                0x000000010007d697 _TToFC4Grid8Document12adjustScrollfS0_FVSC6CGRectS1_ + 87,
>
> 1   AppKit                              0x00007fff84206f8d -[NSClipView _scrollTo:animateScroll:flashScrollerKnobs:] + 1302,
>
> 2   AppKit                              0x00007fff84368209 -[_NSScrollingConcurrentMainThreadSynchronizer _scrollToCononicalOrigin] + 1064,
>
> 3   AppKit                              0x00007fff84367a51 -[_NSScrollingConcurrentMainThreadSynchronizer _synchronize:completionHandler:] + 167,
>
> 4   AppKit                              0x00007fff84367963 __80-[_NSScrollingConcurrentMainThreadSynchronizer initWithSharedData:constantData:]_block_invoke + 144,
>
> 5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010057ed43 _dispatch_client_callout + 8,
>
> ...

Comment: You could try logging `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` from the override to see if it's enlightening as to why it's getting called.

Comment: @KenThomases I logged as you suggested. The first call seems to be some sort of synchronisation call due to the off-main-loop scrolling. Looks safe enough to ignore all rects with bounds of (1,1) in this instance.

Comment: Actually, it looks to me like they are both being called from the same place. It looks like `_scrollToCononicalOrigin` calls `-adjustScroll:` with the bogus rect first as some sort of test and then calls `_scrollTo:animateScroll:flashScrollerKnobs:` to do the real work. Then, that calls `-adjustScroll:` again with the real rect. I'm sure it's always "safe" to return  `[super adjustScroll:proposedVisibleRect]`. It's hard to know if it's safe to ignore the call for whatever logic you plan to implement in `-adjustScroll:` for constraining large scroll movements.

Comment: @KenThomases that effectively answers/closes the question.